# convert rows to string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, datarow

Is there a way to concat rows into a single string in VB code instead of sql query?

I have a query that display something like this:

```
+----------------+
| Col1 Col2 Col3 |
+----------------+
| 1    x    Joe  |
| 1    x    Sue  |
| 2    y    Sam  |
| 2    y    Mary |
+----------------+
```

What I want is something like this:

```
1 x Joe, Sue
2 y Sam, Mary
```

Comment: I'm using a stringbuilder to concat those values
sbData.Append(dr.Item("Col1").ToString() & "" & dr.Item("Col2").ToString() & "" dr.Item("Col3"))

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the Join method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert an array into a string. This is often useful for converting a *single row* into a string. However, what you are asking for is to selectively combine parts of rows into one string. This can be done, but you are going to have to write the method yourself. If you have tried already, please update the question to include your code.

Answer (score 0):

This will do exactly what you want it to do plus it will do it faster

```
    Dim Dt As DataTable = New DataTable

    Dt.Columns.Add("Col1")
    Dt.Columns.Add("Col2")
    Dt.Columns.Add("Col3")

    Dt.Rows.Add("1", "x", "Joe")
    Dt.Rows.Add("1", "x", "Sue")
    Dt.Rows.Add("2", "y", "Sam")
    Dt.Rows.Add("2", "y", "Mary")

    Dim newRows = (From r As DataRow In Dt.AsEnumerable
                  Group By col1 = r("Col1"), col2 = r("Col2") Into newRow = Group
                  Select col1, col2, col3 = String.Join(", ", newRow.Select(Function(x) x("Col3")))).ToList

    For Each item In newRows
        Console.Write(item.col1.ToString & " " & item.col2.ToString & " " & item.col3.ToString)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

> Y you go for vb code its clear and simple to fetch the expected result
>   through query na?

From the question its not clear what the table name is, so i gonna assume the table name is `sampleTable`. now you can fetch the details as you expected by using the following query.

```
select concat(col1,' ' ,col2,' ',group_concat(col3)) as result from sampletable group by col1;
```

Answer (score 0):

@EJD Has a good working solution.  Here is just a variation of coding it:

```
Dt.AsEnumerable() _
    .GroupBy(Function(row) New With {Key .Group1 = row("Col1"), Key .Group2 = row("Col2")}) _
    .Select(Function(row) New With
            {.col1 = row.Key.Group1, .col2 = row.Key.Group2, .col3 = String.Join(", ", row.Select(Function(r) r("Col3")))}) _
    .ToList() _
    .ForEach(Sub(row) Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", row.col1, row.col2, row.col3))
```

Here are two other `Linq` approaches:

1. Uses the `Rows` property of the `DataTable`
2. Uses the `Select()` method of the `DataTable`

We then group the rows together by column 1 & 2.  Once grouped together we make new rows made from the two keys from the grouping and `String.Join()` column 3.

Code sample:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Linq

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim Dt As DataTable = New DataTable
        Dt.Columns.Add("Col1")
        Dt.Columns.Add("Col2")
        Dt.Columns.Add("Col3")

        Dt.Rows.Add("1", "x", "Joe")
        Dt.Rows.Add("1", "x", "Sue")
        Dt.Rows.Add("2", "y", "Sam")
        Dt.Rows.Add("2", "y", "Mary")

        Dt.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow) _
            .GroupBy(Function(row) New With {Key .Group1 = row("Col1"), Key .Group2 = row("Col2")}) _
            .Select(Function(row) New With
                    {.col1 = row.Key.Group1, .col2 = row.Key.Group2, .col3 = String.Join(", ", row.Select(Function(r) r("Col3")))}) _
            .ToList() _
            .ForEach(Sub(row) Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", row.col1, row.col2, row.col3))

        Console.WriteLine()

        Dt.Select() _
            .GroupBy(Function(row) New With {Key .Group1 = row("Col1"), Key .Group2 = row("Col2")}) _
            .Select(Function(row) New With
                    {.col1 = row.Key.Group1, .col2 = row.Key.Group2, .col3 = String.Join(", ", row.Select(Function(r) r("Col3")))}) _
            .ToList() _
            .ForEach(Sub(row) Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", row.col1, row.col2, row.col3))
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

```
1 x Joe, Sue
2 y Sam, Mary

1 x Joe, Sue
2 y Sam, Mary
```